# Mongrel + Outside Access from NAT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Linux box, what is the easiest way to allow another machine on the NAT to access a running mongrel server? (Rails 2.3)

This is for the purpose of browser compatibility checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If both machines are on the same subnet just check the local IP of your Linux box and port to which the Mongrel server is bound. This will give you an URL that looks like `http://192.168.1.111:3000` and should be accessible on the other machine. If it doesn't work then make sure that Mongrel is not configured to bind to `localhost` (127.0.0.1) loopback interface only.
2. If the second machine is outside of NAT you have to configure port forwarding on the router, this will forward traffic directed to a forwarding port on a router to your Linux box. Afterwards your Mongrel server should be accessible from the other machine using the public IP of the router and the forwarding port.

Comment: Apparently, my problem actually was setting a bridge between a VM and the host :)

Comment: Then it would've helped if you had mentioned VM in your question. Anyway good to hear that it works now.